# Python Dictionary Object: SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a dictionary object, it gets created while I use "Statement 1", however I get an error message while try create a dictionary object using same keys and values with "Statement 2".

***Statement 1:***

```
dmap = {0: 'Mon', 1: 'Tue', 2: 'Wed', 3: 'Thu', 
        4: 'Fri', 5: 'Sat', 6: 'Sun'}
```

***Statement 2:***

```
dmap = dict(0='Mon', 1='Tue', 2='Wed', 3='Thu', 
            4='Fri', 5='Sat', 6='Sun'
```

***Error message:***

```
    File "<stdin>", line 1
    SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?
```

Can someone tell me, why am I allowed to create dictionary with integer keys using Statement 1, but not with Statement 2?

***Edited***
Using an updated version of Statement 2, I am able to create dictionary object with below code:

```
dmap = dict(day_0='Mon', day_1='Tue', day_2='Wed', 
            day_3='Thu', day_4='Fri', day_5='Sat', day_6='Sun')
```

Comment: Maybe you should use a list, because the indexes would be the same as the keys

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`dict` is a regular callable which accepts keyword arguments. [As per the Python syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls), keyword arguments are of the form `identifier '=' expression`. [An identifier may not start with a digit](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers), which excludes number literals.

> `keyword_item         ::=  identifier "=" expression`

That `dict` does by default create a dictionary that accepts arbitrary keys does not change the syntax of calls.

Comment: Thanks @MisterMiyagi, your answer explains the concern well.

Answer (score 9):

I ran into the problem because of a missing comma in my dictionary:

```py
item = {
    'a': 1,
    'b': 2
    'c': 3,
    'd': 4
}
```

Note the missing comma between 2 and 'c'

Comment: I had a `:` instead of a `,` somewhere by mistake. The line number on the error wasn't anywhere near it...

Comment: I had a = instead of a :

Comment: 3 years later and this fixed half an hour of head scratching (and then led to a head smack).  Have an upvote, you wonderful person :D

Answer (score 5):

Your confusion probably comes from the fact that you can write things like:

```
d = dict(spam=1, eggs=2)
```

This uses a feature called "keyword arguments" and it only works if the keys are strings. Therefore, your example doesn't work because the keys are integers.

Comment: Note that names are more restrictive than strings. For example, ``dict(spam eggs=2)`` is not allowed, but ``{"spam eggs": 2}`` is.

Answer (score 2):

Because in statement 2 you use "=" instead of ":". you have to use ":".

Right way:

```
dict_obj = {'a': 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
```

Wrong way:

```
dict_obj = {'a' = 1, "b" = 2, "c" = 3}
```

This is just how dictionary works.

Comment: Please do not recommend assigning to names of builtins.

Comment: Statement 2 is not a dictionary literal, it's a function call. You can't use `:` there.

Answer (score 0):

Whereas `0:'Mon'` depicts a key-value pair and gets evaluated as such, 0='Mon' gets evaluated as if you would write 0 = 'Mon' in regular code, which would try to assign 'Mon' to a number, not a variable, and would be like writing 'Potato' = 'Mon' - kind of nonsensical.

Answer (score 0):

you can use integers as key in dict function but not like that you can do that like this:

`dmap = dict([(0 ,'Mon') ,(1, 'Tue'), (2, 'Wed'), (3, 'Thu'),(4, 'Fri'),(5 , 'Sat'), (6, 'Sun')])`

Answer (score -1):

A dictionary in python must contain a `key-value` pair.
like

> dmap = {0 : 'Mon', 1 : 'Tue', 2 : 'Wed', 3 : 'Thu', 4 : 'Fri', 5 : 'Sat', 6 : 'Sun'}

here keys are `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6` and their respective values are `'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'`.
Note: The keys or the values can be of any type.

But in statement 2: `dmap = dict(0 = 'Mon', 1 = 'Tue', 2 = 'Wed', 3 = 'Thu', 4 = 'Fri', 5 = 'Sat', 6 = 'Sun')`
You are assigning values. This is not allowed in python.

Instead you can write like this.

```
dmap = dict({0 : 'Mon', 1 : 'Tue', 2 : 'Wed', 3 : 'Thu', 4 : 'Fri', 5 : 'Sat', 6 : 'Sun'})
```

Answer (score -1):

Check out named parameter
https://treyhunner.com/2018/04/keyword-arguments-in-python/

Simpler way to think about

0 = "Mon"

x= 0

Is x = 0 or x = "Mon"?